# Can Java File object be the cause of "Too many files open" error message on a linux machine

Tags: java, linux, itext

i am running a java program on a redhat linux machine. The program works just fine on my windows laptop but, when i run on the linux server i get a message saying: "Too many open files". Here is the code (roughly - i took out some parts) i'm working with:

```
for(String f : fileList) {
        File file = new File(f);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(f);

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {

                if(condition is true){
                    String s = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(f);
                    File renameFile = new File(s + newfilename );
                    FileUtils.moveFile(file, renameFile);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

The fileList is typically anywhere from 10,000 to 100,000 elements in length. I know that i should probably close the `PdfReader` object - and i will. But, **i was wondering if the regular Java `File` objects can also cause the "Too many open files" error** and if so, how do i properly "close"  those  kinds of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Java `File` object basically wraps a filename, but it doesn't hold an open file handle until you use it to open a stream or reader.

Answer (score 2):

Call close() on your handlers to release resources:

```
reader.close();
```

Comment: The `File` objects don't matter as far as the "too many files" issue goes ?

Comment: The file object mainly provided the location info, and wasn't itself "open".